# Variable's scope in a switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I think I don't understand how the scope works in a switch case.

Can someone explain to me why the first code doesn't compile but the second does ?

Code 1 :

```
 int key = 2;
 switch (key) {
 case 1:
      String str = "1";
      return str;
 case 2:
      String str = "2"; // duplicate declaration of "str" according to Eclipse.
      return str;
 }
```

Code 2 :

```
 int key = 2;
 if (key == 1) {
      String str = "1";
      return str;
 } else if (key == 2) {
      String str = "2";
      return str;
 }
```

How come the scope of the variable "str" is not contained within Case 1 ?

If I skip the declaration of case 1 the variable "str" is never declared...

Comment: Made an answer to the original question about the [changes in the local variable scoping and use of switch expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238424/1746118) with [tag:java-12]

Answer (score 213, accepted):

I'll repeat what others have said: the scope of the variables in each `case` clause corresponds to the whole `switch` statement. You can, however, create further nested scopes with braces as follows:

```
int key = 2;
switch (key) {
case 1: {
    String str = "1";
    return str;
  }
case 2: {
    String str = "2";
    return str;
  }
}
```

The resulting code will now compile successfully since the variable named `str` in each `case` clause is in its own scope.

Also note that the scope for `case:` (sans-`{}`) goes to the 'global' `switch` scope. And after that every other `case` scope (with or without `{}`) will receive those variables in a way uncommon for nested java scope, they can't be overridden. So, for example, adding `{}` only to the second `case` would still give you the same error as it would get the variable from the first one injected, but adding braces to the first one would compile. I am not sure this is defined as such on the spec, but it what happens on most implementations.

Comment: Listen to this guy. He's right.

Comment: Correct. But I would be very annoyed with any programmer in my team who uses this "syntax" without a VERY good reason. It's a recipe for confusion and bugs.  It visually hides the fact that the first case block (if it not were for the `return`) "continues" even after the closing brace - and helps to forget the `break`.

Comment: also: use `break` for maintainability and bug prevention! even if not required.

Comment: @mightyuhu break won't work as there is return statement...at least for Java...C or C++ it is fine...

Comment: @Boy you are probably right. However, this was not my original point actually.  i think those premature returns lead to all kind of maintenance and bug masquerading problems not to mention dead code or cyclomatic complexity. So as a general advice one should avoid such constructs at least in cases that ain't trivial

Comment: Not only to help visually `break` will help javascript performance in very long switch statements by exiting the statement without evaluating the rest of it !

Comment: @MgGm the question is about Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: Makes sense even in 2022 :)

Answer (score 10):

The scope of the variable is the whole `switch` statement -- all cases and default, if included.

Here are some other options...

Option 1:

```
int key = 2;
switch (key) {
case 1:
     return "1";
case 2:
     return "2";
}
```

Option 2:

```
int key = 2;
String str = null;
switch (key) {
case 1:
     str = "1";
     return str;
case 2:
     str = "2";
     return str;
}
```

Comment: Option 3:

```java
switch (key) {
case 1: {
     String str = "1";
     return str;
  }
case 2: {
     String str = "2";
     return str;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be assuming that each `case` is a block with its own local scope, as if/else blocks. It's not.

It's important to correct this conceptual mistake, because otherwise you'll end falling in the frequent trap of forgetting the `break` inside the `case`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a valid question, and scope assumption for case statment is unavoidable.
Adjusting ourselves to it because java writer has made this not correct.

e.g. if statement by default take first line in its scope than what's wrong with cases where the end of case is explicitly closed by break statement. Hence the declaration in case 1: should not be available in case 2 and it has parallel scope but not nested.

Answer (score 0):

Several cases can be executed in one switch statement. So..

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a variable exists between the braces of the switch and if statements. In example Code 1 the switch braces enclose both declarations of the variables which will cause the compiler to error as the name to variable binding will have already been made.

In the other example it is ok because both variables are declared within their own braces (scope).

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the scope of the String declaration is within the switch statement therefore it is shown as duplicate while in the second the string is enclosed within curly braces which limits the scope within the if/else conditions,therefore it is not an error in the second case.