# Why object declared after one case label is available in others?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable scope in a switch case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894119/variable-scope-in-a-switch-case)

I've got a code like this:

```
switch(a) {
case b:
 Object o = new Object();
 return o;
case c:
 o = new Object();
 return o;
 }
```

and i'm interesting why it's possible to use variable declared after first case label in the second one even if first state will never be reached?

Comment: It is an exact duplicate therefore violating the rules of SO. Shame! :)

Comment: @Jan - Without knowing the word 'scope' it may have been hard to find it. No shame. :)

Comment: Ok, taking back the 'Shame' word.

Comment: Asking duplicates isn't a crime, especially if the question is phrased differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite being in different cases, the variables local to the `switch` statement are in the same block, which means they are in the same scope.

As far as I know, new scope in Java is only created in a new block of code. A block of code (with more than one line) has to be surrounded by curly braces. The code in the cases of a switch statement is *not* surrounded by curly braces, so it is part of the whole statement's scope.

However, you can actually introduce a new scope to the statement by adding curly braces:

```
switch (cond) {
case 1:{
     Object o = new Object();
}
    break;
case 2:{
    // Object o is not defined here!
}
    break;
}
```

Comment: Now tell me you didn't copy it over from the one flaged as duplicate :)

Comment: I actually posted before I saw the comment. That said, I should go over there and see if there is anything left to steal ;)