# Declaring and initializing variables within Java switches

Tags: java, scope, initialization, switch-statement, declaration

I have a crazy question about Java switches.

```
int key = 2;

switch (key) {
    case 1:
        int value = 1;
        break;
    case 2:
        value = 2;
        System.out.println(value);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Scenario 1 - When the `key` is two it successfully print the value as 2.

Scenario 2 - When I'm going to comment `value = 2` in `case 2:` it squawks saying the *The local variable value may not have been initialized*.

Questions : 

Scenario 1 : If the execution flow doesn't go to `case 1:` (when the `key = 2`), then how does it know the type of the value variable as `int`?

Scenario 2 : If the compiler knows the type of the value variable as `int`, then it must have accessed to the `int value = 1;` expression in `case 1:`.(Declaration and Initialization). Then why does it sqawrk When I'm going to comment `value = 2` in `case 2:`, saying the *The local variable value may not have been initialized*.

Comment: It's not a crazy question, it's a very good question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable's scope in a switch case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894119/variables-scope-in-a-switch-case)

Comment: @PhilippeCarriere Actually, I think it should be in reverse - the answer here is better (even if the post is newer) since there's a direct reference to the JLS, and summarizes well the issue covered in different answers in that post. [See also](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251938/should-i-flag-a-question-as-duplicate-if-it-has-received-better-answers).

Comment: @Tunaki The description for a duplicate starts with "This question has been asked before". I'm reading that as the later one should be marked as a duplicate of the earlier one. But I do agree that this one has nice elements. Maybe they should be merged somehow?

Comment: Also a lot of questions on SO are marked as duplicate of my original question, so if you decide that it's better to mark this one as the new original, please fix all the links to refer to this one instead of mine.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Switch statements are odd in terms of scoping, basically. From [section 6.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in the local variable declaration statement.

In your case, `case 2` is in the same *block* as `case 1` and appears after it, even though `case 1` will never execute... so the local variable is in scope and available for *writing* despite you logically never "executing" the declaration. (A declaration isn't really "executable" although initialization is.)

If you comment out the `value = 2;` assignment, the compiler still knows which variable you're referring to, but you won't have gone through any execution path which assigns it a value, which is why you get an error as you would when you try to read any other not-definitely-assigned local variable.

I would strongly recommend you *not* to use local variables declared in other cases - it leads to highly confusing code, as you've seen. When I introduce local variables in switch statements (which I try to do rarely - cases should be very short, ideally) I usually prefer to introduce a new scope:

```
case 1: {
    int value = 1;
    ...
    break;
}
case 2: {
    int value = 2;
    ...
    break;
}
```

I believe this is clearer.

Comment: +1 for "A declaration isn't really "executable" although initialization is.". And thank you for the advises too Skeet.

Comment: With the JEP-325 integrated, the [picture of the scope of local variables has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238424/1746118) and one can use the same name across cases instead of switch blocks. Though it relies on similar block coding as well. Also, the value assigned to a variable per switch case would be much convenient with the switch expressions.

Comment: Points for adding a new scope with braces. Didn't even know you could do that.

Answer (score 22):

The variable has been declared (as an int), but not initialized (assigned an initial value).  Think of the line:

```
int value = 1;
```

As:

```
int value;
value = 1;
```

The `int value` part tells the compiler at compile time that you have a variable called value which is an int. The `value = 1` part initializes it, but that happens at run-time, and doesn't happen at all if that branch of the switch isn't entered.

Comment: +1 for the nice explanation of declaration and initialization in compile time and runtime.

Answer (score 18):

From  http://www.coderanch.com/t/447381/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/variable-initialization-within-case-block

> Declarations are processed at compile time and do not depend on the
>   execution flow of your code. Since `value` is declared within the local
>   scope of the switch block, it is useable anywhere in that block from
>   the point of its declaration.

Comment: why is this answer being upvoted? it doesn't answer the question, unlike paul or skeet's answer...

Comment: It does. So, +1, a penny, from my side too.

Answer (score 7):

With the integration of [JEP 325: Switch Expressions (Preview)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325) in JDK-12 early access builds. There are certain changes that could be seen from [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810847/1746118)  -

1. ***Local Variable Scope*** - The local variables in the switch cases can now be local to the case itself *instead of the entire switch block*. An example (similar to what Jon had attempted syntactically as well) considering the `Day` enum class for further explanation :

   ```
   public enum Day {
       MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY
   }

   // some another method implementation
   Day day = Day.valueOf(scanner.next());
   switch (day) {
       case MONDAY,TUESDAY -> {
           var temp = "mon-tue";
           System.out.println(temp);
       }
       case WEDNESDAY,THURSDAY -> {
           var temp = Date.from(Instant.now()); // same variable name 'temp'
           System.out.println(temp);
       }
       default ->{
           var temp = 0.04; // different types as well (not mandatory ofcourse)
           System.out.println(temp);
       }
   }
   ```
2. ***Switch Expressions*** - If the intent is to assign a value to a variable and then make use of it, once can make use of the switch expressions. e.g.

   ```
   private static void useSwitchExpression() {
       int key = 2;
       int value = switch (key) {
           case 1 ->  1;
           case 2 -> 2;
           default -> {break 0;}
       };
       System.out.println("value = " + value); // prints 'value = 2'
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This Explanation might help.

```
    int id=1;

    switch(id){
        default: 
            boolean b= false; // all switch scope going down, because there is no scope tag

        case 1:
            b = false;
        case 2:{
            //String b= "test"; you can't declare scope here. because it's in the scope @top
            b=true; // b is still accessible
        }
        case 3:{
            boolean c= true; // case c scope only
            b=true; // case 3 scope is whole switch
        }
        case 4:{
            boolean c= false; // case 4 scope only
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java spec:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11

> The case of abrupt completion because of a break with a label is handled by the general rule for labeled statements (§14.7).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7

Labeled statements:

> LabeledStatement:
>       Identifier : Statement
>
> LabeledStatementNoShortIf:
>       Identifier : StatementNoShortIf
>
> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no goto statement;
>   identifier statement labels are used with break (§14.15) or continue
>   (§14.16) statements appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.
>
> The scope of a label of a labeled statement is the immediately
>   contained Statement.

In other words, case 1, case 2 are labels within the switch statement. break and continue statements can be applied to labels.

Because labels share the scope of the statement, all variables defined within labels share the scope of the switch statement.