# Local variables in Java switch control

Tags: java, switch-statement

I found this case a bit peculiar:

```
    int x = 1;
    switch(x){
          case 0 :
             boolean b = false;
             break;
          case 1 :
             b = true; //will compile just right
             System.out.println(b); //will print true
             break;
          default:
                 System.out.println(b); //will not compile
       }
```

I just think this is confusing. Local variables are said to be accessible within the entire block of codes. Sure, `b` is within a switch block so I can understand it is accessible in a different case, even though this seems to contradict the switch flow that it may not go through the first case, and therefore, may not declare and initialize `b`.

But isn't this again contradicting if `b` meanwhile is still inaccessible in the default branch?

Is there any special execution for local variable declarations in a case branch that it will run whether the case has been matched or not? If yes, then why can't default branch access it?

Edit for the duplicate flag: The question here is not about how the variable declared in a case branch is not local (as I noted above), but instead, why the local variable declared inside a case is accessible outside it, but not the value it has been initialized with.

Found a similar question that I believe answers my question: [Declaring and initializing variables within Java switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810768/declaring-and-initializing-variables-within-java-switches)

Comment: what is the compilation error for the use of `b` in default? not declared or not initialized - very different

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger in eclipse, it says it may not have been initialized.

Comment: so the problem is not *"still inaccessible in the default branch"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is that the default case means: no other case was taken.

The switch construct allows you to have local variables within its overall scope, but still each "read" must see a prior "write".

And the compiler can easily detect that the default case didn't see a initialization for *b*.

Beyond that, the reason why you can have such assignments in different cases is: the overall switch statement only has **one** "switch block".

See the [Java Language Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) for further details!

Comment: And the "make the code correct" fix is to move the declaration and initialization of ```b``` to before the switch.

Answer (score 1):

`b` should be accessible in the default block, but you did not initialize it.

Try:

```
default: 
    b = true; 
    System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: I see and understand. But how come the declaration of 'b' has been "recognized" inside a case that may or may not be run, but not its initialization?

Comment: short story: because Java is specified that way (roughly: variable is in scope inside the block where the it is declared; initialization is a statement that is executed in the order in appears)

Answer (score 1):

`b` scope is the `switch` block. The reason of the compilation error is `b` in the `default` block might not be initialized.

If you want `b` to exists only in the `case` block then you need to wrap it with `{}`:

```
switch(x) {
  case 0 : {
    boolean b = false;
    break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if `x=1` it will execute `case 1:` and since you have a `break`statement in `case 1:`, once it encounters the `break`statement it exits out of the switch and will never reach the `default` case. So if you want the program to execute the `default` case either change `x`to another number other than `0 and 1` or remove the `break`statement from `case 1:`