# Frame code "case" in the "switch" by curly braces - {}

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I never saw that code "case" in the "switch" was framed by curly braces - {}. Can I use braces to hide variables in case? Or is it a bad practice? What are the possible consequences?

I need to use the switch, in which each case is formed from the same type of variables (which in my opinion is better to keep the same name) but which have different values.

```
Dialog dialog;
switch (id) {
    case ID_1: {
        String[] keys = ...; // some array
        String[] values = ...;
        ...
        return dialog;
    }
    ...
        case ID_2: {
        String[] keys = ...; // different values
        ...
        return dialog;
    }
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use braces to hide variables in case?

Yes you can.

> Or is it a bad practice?

It is possibly a sign that you could refactor your code - but hard to tell without seeing what the code does in each `case`.

> What are the possible consequences?

None apart from limiting the scope of those variables, which is your goal.

Comment: To your last point, the scope is already limited to each case, so including or not including braces actually shouldn't change anything unless I'm not thinking about a certain scenario...

Comment: No the scope of each case is the whole switch block. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3894215/829571

Comment: if that were the case then wouldn't you be able to assign to a variable in a preceding case statement?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed very common practice when you need different local variables in the individual cases.

If you need a lot of them, though, especially when they are all almost identical, it might be a sign that the code is getting to be overly copy-pasted.

Unless the code in each case has significant differences except for the data, as an example, it might make some sense to keep the keys and values in an array or hastable instead.

```
keys   = dialog_data[id].keys;
values = dialog_data[id].values;
```

The question does not really contain enough information to know if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if there are some constants in code, you might export them into another class with public-static-final fields, it may fix your problem. I can't say more, because we can't see whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the dialog data in a HashTable. In that way you can traverse the keyset and change the data values accordingly.