# Android: How to use setOnClickListener/onClick for 20 different buttons?

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, android-activity, onclicklistener

In my Android App there is a activity with 20 buttons in it. Each button have to go to another activity/page.
I've tried several ways but i can't use a intent so much times.

Option 1:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

switch(v.getId()){

case R.id.ivNB: 
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoordBrabant.class);
   this.startActivity(intent);
   break;

case R.id.ivZH1: 
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ZuidHolland.class);
   this.startActivity(intent);
   break;

/**** End so 20 more ****/
}
```

In the second case, the intent is not good, did i can't use more intents in 1 switch?

Option 2:

```
ivNB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoordBrabant.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
    ivZeeland.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Zeeland.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
/**** End so 20 more ****/
```

This way work with 5 of maby 10 the same, but with 20 the App crashes.

Option 3:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == ivGelderland){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Gelderland.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (v == ivNB) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoordBrabant.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (v == ivLimburg) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Limburg.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
/**** End so 20 more ****/
```

This way doesn't work at all, did i do something wrong here??

Please can someone help me, i'm struggling a couple of days with it now!

Thank you!

Comment: "I've tried several ways but i can't use a intent so much times." Why not?

Comment: Why are you not declaring The intent only once in first case and use that same object in another cases?? In your Code you are using same name for multiple variables which is a duplicate local variable error !

Comment: @323go I think Imran is simply saying that you could declare `Intent intent = null;` then set `intent = ...` in the `switch`, then use `if (intent != null) startActivity(intent);` after the `switch`... which would work, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @323go you need a better understanding of variable scope in a switch-case IMHO.  The scope of the variables in each case clause corresponds to the whole switch statement unless braces are used. Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894119/variable-scope-in-a-switch-case

Comment: Cross check that you have declared all the 20 activities in manifest file.

Comment: Do what Rohit O said, code should work just fine the way you did it, except for the first.Just a bit dirty code, clean answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Define a HashMap where the key is the Integer value of the view.getId() and the value is the class for the Activity.

```
private static HashMap<Integer,Class> activityMap = new HashMap<Intger,Class>();
static {
    activityMap.put( R.id.ivNB, NoordBrabant.class );
    activityMap.put( R.id.ivZH1, ZuidHolland.class );
    //...
}

// use this in the layout xml file for all the buttons onClick attribute
public void handleBtnClicked( View vw ) {
    startActivity( new Intent( this, activityMap.get( vw.getId() ) );
}
```

Comment: Cleanest solution imho, might even check if the hashmap contains the button id, if not throw an exception. So it will be clear fast when you forgot to add an entry in the hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [android:onClick xml attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aonClick) to map buttons clicks to methods.

So you can basically have 20 methods in your activity like the following

```
public void buttonXpressed( View view ){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MyNextActivity.class));
}
```

And in your layout xml

```
<Button .... 
    android:onClick="buttonXpressed"
   ... >
</Button>
```

Comment: This isn't necessary at all, there's nothing with setting `onClick` listeners in Java. In fact, I do it exclusively.

Comment: You'll need to make your class `implements OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom and override onClick event then just pass target activity.

// custom button

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.util.AttributeSet;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;


public class MyBtn extends Button implements OnClickListener {

    private Context context;
    private Class _class;

    public MyBtn(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
        this.context = context;
    }

    private void init() {
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setActivity(Class _class) {
        this._class = _class;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, _class);
        this.context.startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

// your layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.example.mixed.MyBtn
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

     <com.example.mixed.MyBtn
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

      <com.example.mixed.MyBtn
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

       <com.example.mixed.MyBtn
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

// your main activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

         com.example.mixed.MyBtn btn1 = (com.example.mixed.MyBtn)findViewById(R.id.button1);         
         com.example.mixed.MyBtn btn2 = (com.example.mixed.MyBtn)findViewById(R.id.button2);
         com.example.mixed.MyBtn btn3 = (com.example.mixed.MyBtn)findViewById(R.id.button3);
         com.example.mixed.MyBtn btn4 = (com.example.mixed.MyBtn)findViewById(R.id.button4);

         btn1.setActivity(MainActivity2.class);
         btn2.setActivity(MainActivity3.class);
         btn3.setActivity(MainActivity4.class);
         btn4.setActivity(MainActivity5.class);         

    }   

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use your option 1 (Declare Intent before switch):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent;
switch(v.getId()){

case R.id.ivNB: 
   intent = new Intent(this, NoordBrabant.class);
   this.startActivity(intent);
   break;

case R.id.ivZH1: 
   intent = new Intent(this, ZuidHolland.class);
   this.startActivity(intent);
   break;

/**** End so 20 more ****/
}
```