# Java Switch use variable in multiple cases best practice

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to have a switch statement like the following:

```
switch (something)
{
    case 1:
        int a = 3;
        ...
        break;
    case 2:
        int a = 4;
        ....
        break;
}
```

This does not work because a can not be redefined in that scope. I see the following options:

1. just go with "a = 4" in case 2
2. put each case in braces
3. define the variable before the switch statement
4. use a different variable name in case 2

I don't really like any of those four. Which of those is the way to go, or am i missing the best solution?

I saw questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15528742/re-instantiating-variables-in-switch-case), which suggest using braces, but they are not about the best way to do it, but about getting it to work at all.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `switch` in the context of your code? Also, why do you dislike these options? Is it one of those things where they just annoy you? Or do you have an objective design reason? What would you prefer in a perfect world?

Comment: I would pefer it like written above. (Like with braces but without needing to add extra braces) I dislike 4 because it kind of is a workaround, and I dislike 1 because it is harder to see. 2 and 3 are things i am fine with, but are not "perfect". I was just asking myself what would be the "right way" to do it or if there is an even better way.

Comment: How about `int a = 2 + something;` without more details, this appears to be he simplest.

Comment: @peter: the real world is not as simple as the simplified sample, it is not about an int that can be calculated somehow but about syntax. But using braces seems to be the prefered choice. Will accept tomorrow if no other opinions arise.

Comment: @Flo I agree with using `case _: { /* local vars */ }` pattern.  My point ways that best practice is to make the code as simple as possible, this often means restructuring the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are catching any exception with an illegalstateexception and using a default block.

```
default:
     doSomething();
     break;
```

The [oracle style guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) does not use braces. It also says that a falls through comment should be added wherever a statement has no break.

However, anything with more than one line can be wrapped in braces with no performance penalty, for readability and reliability. The braces tell the compiler to create a new scope and execute that code as a block. If all you do is change a, then it is not really necessary. If you can write your switch case statement on one line without braces, do it. Many things in java don't do braces in one line instances including if statements.

Next, you can redefine any variable you need to re-use or set in the statements outside of the switch statement. This would be the best practice to minimize continual instantiation of your integers.

If there is more then one line,you should try making a few methods then, go with:

```
int a=0;

switch (something)
{
    case 1:{
        a = 3;
        ...
        break;
     }
     case 2:{
        a = 4;
        ....
       break;
    }
    default:
    {
       try{
           throw new IllegalStateException();
       }catch(IllegalStateException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
   } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The braces is the right way to do it.  {} creates a new scope, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Map:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> caseMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
    put(1, 3);
    put(2, 4);
}};

int a = caseMap.get(something);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my example was just a very simplified one. There is code to be executed in the cases (hence the "...") so this will not work.