# Java switch statement - using a variable, in a case, declared in another case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm not new to Java but this is a thing that i have never seen before.
Supposing have a switch case, declaring a variable in case 0 makes the variable visible in the other cases that is a strange thing and i think is not in the java style.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String _case = "case";

    switch (_case) {
        case "1":
            String foo = "foo";
            break;
        case "2":
            String bar = "bar";
            break;
        case "case":
            foo = "foo";
            System.out.println(foo);
            // System.out.println(bar); //Variable bar might not have been initialized
            break;
    }
}
```

If case `1` is not validated why and how the `String foo` variable becomes declared?

[Execute](https://onlinegdb.com/SJ3IdmTer) the code online

Comment: I found the answer, I was surprisedl I could've sworn I was correct

Comment: yes it was very strange for me too seeing something like this :D

Comment: Another question == another post...  1 question per post please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set `foo = "foo"` inside of your last case, it guarantees the variable was instantiated at that point. There's no moment in which `bar` is instantiated in the last case, giving you this error. This is due to the fact that the scope of a variable in a case is equal to that of the entire switch statement. More info on [other questions about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894119/variables-scope-in-a-switch-case)

Comment: Yes i know, but i declared the foo in the case one! Why it's visible in the last case? This is my question

Comment: @RobertoManfreda The scope of a variable in a case is equal to the *entire* switch statement